# How to iterate through a pixel array with SDL2

Tags: c, sdl-2

I try to go through the pixels of an image to change their color component but I still get the same error:

> Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Here is the function code:

```
{
    SDL_Surface *retour = NULL;
    SDL_Color color = {255, 255, 255, 255};
    int i, j, w = (int) s->w, h = (int) s->h;
    Uint32 *src = NULL;
    if(SDL_LockSurface(s) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur SDL_LockSurface : %s", SDL_GetError());
        goto lock_surface_fail;
    }
    src = (Uint32 *)s->pixels;

    for(i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < w; j++)
        {
            SDL_GetRGB(src[i * w + j], s->format, &color.r, &color.g, &color.b);
            Uint8 gray = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3;
            src[i * w + j] = SDL_MapRGB(s->format, gray, gray, gray);
        }
    }
    printf("%d sur %d", w, h);
    retour = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormatFrom(src, s->w, s->h, 32, s->pitch, s->format->format);
    if(NULL == retour)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur SDL_CreateRGBSurface : %s",
                SDL_GetError());
    }

alloc_memory_fail:
    SDL_UnlockSurface(s);
lock_surface_fail:
    return retour;

}
```

It should be noted that when I comment out the loop the code executes well and I can display the image which clearly proves that the iteration syntax of the arrray is incorrect

```
for(i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < w; j++)
        {
            SDL_GetRGB(src[i * w + j], s->format, &color.r, &color.g, &color.b);
            Uint8 gray = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3;
            src[i * w + j] = SDL_MapRGB(s->format, gray, gray, gray);
        }
    }
```

entire code :(https://pastebin.com/wR4CEqKd)

Comment: Perhaps unrelated, but you should use `pitch` instead of `w` to access a pixel

Comment: @Nelfeal have you ever looked through a pixel array? I just need a reference code !

Comment: See [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/190012/how-to-read-argb-pixel-data-from-sdl2-surface-and-store-them-in-an-array) for example. It's really just a matter of using `pitch` instead of `w` in `src[i * w + j]`, so like `src[i * pitch + j]`

Comment: SDL_GetRGB() takes an offset into the pixel data.  You also need to keep in mind that each pixel in this image is 4 bytes (bitDepth = 32 and Bpp = 4).  So, I think you mean stride not pitch where stride = w * Bpp;  offset = row * stride + col * bpp; Then access use src[offset]

Comment: @Syntactics What you think of as "stride" is pitch in [SDL_Surface](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_Surface). Here, it's assumed that bpp = 4, which matches with the type of `src` (`Uint32`).